# how to change access component level of jframe in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, oop, netbeans, netbeans-7

I'm trying to use user management levels in my java swing project. I want to disable few buttons to users which only admin can click. So in my project I designed my home page using JFrame. And I have few buttons called Stock, Invoice, Grn etc..

[image: Home]

In each button I changed access level as "public" by using properties==> cord==> Variable modifiers.

[image: Login]

But in Home JFrame I couldn't change the access level as "public". 
In my login frame I when I'm logging as a user I want to code like given below. But still I can't call Home.hm.btnStock because I can't change the user level of Home.

In login interface

```
LogToHome lh = new LogToHome();
public static Login log;

     private void btnLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    lh.logHome(comboUn, jpass);
}
```

in LogToHome java class

```
        public void logHome(JComboBox combo, JPasswordField jpass) {
    if (combo.getSelectedItem().equals("--SELECT--")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select User name");
    } else if (jpass.getText().isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insert your Password");
        jpass.grabFocus();
    } else {
        try {
            String un = combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String pass = new String(jpass.getPassword());
            ResultSet rs = new JDBC().getData("SELECT * FROM login WHERE un='" + un.trim() + "' AND pw='" + pass + "'");
            if (rs.next()) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login OK");
                Login.log.setVisible(false);
                if (un == "user") {
                    Home.hm = new Home();
                    Home.hm.btnStock.setenabled(false);
                    Home.hm.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    Home.hm = new Home();
                    Home.hm.setVisible(true);
                }

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter valid user name or password");

                jpass.setText("");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, this.getClass().getName() + " " + e);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "In my login frame I when I'm logging as a user I want to code like given below. But still I can't call Home.hm.btnStock because I can't change the user level of Home."

Don't compare Strings with `==`. Use `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()`

```
if (un == "user")
```

Should be

```
if ("user".equals(un))
```

Using `==`, the case below won't be true

```
if (un == "user") {
      Home.hm = new Home();
      Home.hm.btnStock.setenabled(false);
      Home.hm.setVisible(true);
```

---

Also this line `Home.hm.btnStock.setenabled(false);` looks suspect. Should be `setEnabled` with a capital `E`, unless you have a custom `setenabled` method

Comment: ok thanks. :) but still I can't find a way to access button on Home JFrame.

Comment: in  Home.hm.btnStock.setenabled(false); When I type Home.hm I don't have a suggetion as btnStock.setenabled(false);

Comment: This line `Home.hm.btnStock.setenabled(false);` looks suspect. Should be `setEnabled` with a capital `E`, unless you have a custom `setenabled` method

Comment: What exactly is `Home.hm.`?

Comment: those methods are working after your answer.. :) Still I'm having null point exception in LogToHome method..

Comment: please wait. I restrted netbeans